# Autologin at boot on Ubuntu 20.04.2 after Security Updates doesn't work anymore

Tags: boot, login

Autologin at boot on Ubuntu 20.04.2, I got to work 2 years ago. Today I finally got approval to test Security Updates. Everything went find except, Autologin will not switch to tty6 by itself. When I manually go to tty6, then it logs in by itself. But I am not always there to do this. Any Idees?

Comment: I used "xargs apt install -y < Security-Updates.txt" command. Where in Security-Updates.txt was a list of only the Security Updates needed. I am only allowed to do security updates, not an Upgrade. If I missed someting here, please inform me.